# mailer.rb file syntax fail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Why is it that this method produces an empty variable and therefore empty body?

custom_email.text.erb

```
<%=@message%>
```

user_mailer.rb

```
default from: "Name <name@domain.com>"
def custom_email(email, subject, message)
  mail to: email, subject: "Name || #{subject}"
  @message = message
end
```

---

While this method works:

```
mail to: email, subject: "Name || #{subject}", body: message
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write this

```
default from: "Name <name@domain.com>"
def custom_email(email, subject, message)
  @message = message
  mail to: email, subject: "Name || #{subject}"
end
```

instead of

```
default from: "Name <name@domain.com>"
def custom_email(email, subject, message)
  mail to: email, subject: "Name || #{subject}"
  @message = message
end
```

then it will consider @message

Comment: right. that makes sense wow...I'm exhausted. I was sending mail before setting the variable and therefore the body was empty